# Windows directories become backslashes in filenames in git repo

Tags: git, aptana

I have a developer who is on Windows, running git under Cygwin. He's also running the Aptana plugin in Eclipse.

When pushing files to the repo from Cygwin things are fine, but when he pushed from the Aptana plugin then Github isn't showing those files in directories, instead it's put the Windows directory separator into the filename, e.g. there is a file named 'test\newfile.php' in the top level of the repo.

Github support has checked the repo and tells me that 'test\newfile.php' is what was pushed, so the problem must lie in the plugin.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Which version of Aptana is your developer using?

Comment: Contact Aptana support maybe? Or try using msysgit?

Comment: This is the latest version of Aptana Studio - 3.0.5. I'll try and put together a reproducible case to add to their bug tracker, other than that they don't really have a support contact - they just point people here. Fair enough for a free product. This developer is the last Windows holdout in a team using MacOS and Linux desktops. It's becoming increasingly apparent that unless you are doing .NET development, getting Windows to behave is an uphill battle.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like maybe it's related to this: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3718
We weren't converting PATH properly for cygwin installs.

Filing a bug with details and a reproducible case would be very helpful, as we're not sure what we need to do differently for cygwin. A workaround is to use minGW, msysgit (which we pre-package for use), or if you're doing ruby/rails work using the msysgit inside RailsInstaller.